# How can I create Local commands definitions in equations?

Tags: macros, programming, grouping

I would like to use small local macro expansion similar to how `\newcommand` works but on a per environment basis.

Something that would expand

```
\[
  \begin{local}
  \local{\poly}[2][x]{#1^2 - #1^#2}
  \poly{a} - \poly[y]{3} > 0
  \end{local}
\]
```

to

```
\[
  {x^2 - x^a} - {y^2 - y^3} > 0
\]
```

Is it possible at all to have a similar environment without having to declare `\poly` in the preamble?

(I added the grouping tag because it sounded relevant from the description, I am not sure if it is)

Comment: You don't need a wrapping environment, because `\[...\]` already provides grouping. Use `\newcommand` instead of `\local` and you're done.

Comment: @afiori And don't omit braces around `#1` and `#2` in such situations. Use something like this: `\newcommand*{\poly}[2][x]{{#1}^2 - {#1}^{#2}}`. Otherwise, if you pass an argument consisting of several tokens, you'll likely be disappointed by the result.

Comment: @egreg, wow, I do not know why I was so sure that It wasn't  possible.